# Handling file uploads in App Engine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

I am trying to implement a file upload solution using app engine and python. The thing which I am struggling with checking whether there is actually a file attached to the form or not. I am setting the enctype="multipart/form-data" and in principle it works. My python handler looks like this:

```
fileupload = self.request.POST["content"]

if not fileupload:
    return self.error(400)
```

This works if there is no file attached. However if there is a file attached it gives the following error:

```
  File "D:\eclipse_dev\workspace\test\src\handlers.py", line 351, in post
    if not fileupload:
  File "C:\Python25\lib\cgi.py", line 633, in __len__
    return len(self.keys())
  File "C:\Python25\lib\cgi.py", line 609, in keys
    raise TypeError, "not indexable"
TypeError: not indexable
```

How can I safely check that an upload is present before doing anything else in the handler?

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've got this working using:

```
import cgi
.
.
fileupload = self.request.POST["content"]

if not isinstance(fileupload, cgi.FieldStorage):
   return self.error(400)
```

Not sure if that's the best solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: This works for me so I am going to accept my own answer. I hope that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
fileupload = self.request.POST["content"]

if fileupload is None:
    return self.error(400)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not trigger the error. I'm quite new to python. Is there any otherway of checking the value of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine's self.request.get() method handles POST data just fine:

["The request object provides a get() method that returns values for arguments parsed from the query and from POST data."](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestdata.html)

Try this instead:

```
def post(self):
  fileupload = self.request.get('content')
  if not fileupload:
    self.error(400)
  else:
    # Proceed normally
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a small tutorial about file upload to GAE.
http://verysimplescripts.blogspot.jp/
There is a completely working solution included as well.